# Calling a function with more than one parameter in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, ibaction

I was wondering if an IBaction can have more than 1 parameter.
This is my IBAction.

```
-(IBAction)addToBestelling:(NSString *)Pro_id:(NSString *)Pro_naam:(NSString *)Pro_prijs:(NSString *)Pro_aantal{
    arrayProductBestelling = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    arrayBestelling = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [arrayProductBestelling addObject:Pro_id];
    [arrayProductBestelling addObject:Pro_naam];
    [arrayProductBestelling addObject:Pro_prijs];
    [arrayProductBestelling addObject:Pro_aantal];

    [arrayBestelling addObject:arrayProductBestelling];

    NSLog(@"%@",arrayBestelling);  



}
```

But how do i call this function on my button? I tried this, but doesn't worked.

```
cell.btnadd addTarget:self action:@selector(addToBestelling:strId:strNaam:strPrijs:strAantal) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. *IBAction* calls can happen to selectors with maximum 2 arguments (the UIControl that caught the event, and the event itself).

The button doesn't 'know' the values you'd require for the parameters - it is designed to facilitate user interaction.

You probably want something more along the line of

```
- (IBAction) handleButton:(id) sender
{
[self addToBestelling:some_string Pro_id:some_id Pro_naam: another_string Pro_prijs: yet_another_string];
}
```

Comment: You are correct that you cannot have arbitrary parameters as the OP requests, but note that `UIControl` can send 0, 1 or 2 parameters. It can pass the event as well as the sender. See "Target-Action in UIKit" for how this works. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html

Comment: Of course! I've never used it but that is indeed true. I've modified the answer, thanks.